# How to Delete Lollipop Update From" LG Nexus 5"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, nexus-5, ota-update

My LG Nexus 5 shows a Lollipop update prompt. I do not want this prompt to sit on top of the device.

How do I remove this Notification from the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

**Download this app** : [3C Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free&hl=en)  (from Google Play)
Go to :

> Application Manager > Apps Tab > Google Play Services > Manage Button > Permissions Button > Services Tab

then touch : uncheck `update.SystemUpdateService`

Reboot.

There may be another way availabe for doing this, example :

**Go to :**

> `Lollipop Settings > Apps`

and find this Program then, touch for `uncheck Show Notification` if availabe in Lollipop.

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the software update notification. Just Long press the notification you will get a small icon "App info".  Press on it you will be directed to app settings.  Uncheck the show notifications option. You won't get any further notifications about system update..